# How to display specific child page template in wordpress

Tags: templates

I am trying to display a child page template of a certain specific parent page.

```
<?php 
    if(has_children()){ 
        // This is a parent page 
        get_template_part('content', 'parent'); 
    }elseif(is_page() && $post->post_parent ){ 
        // This is a child page of certain parent page
        get_template_part('content', 'child');

        //*THIS PART BELOW HAS REFUSED TO WORK FOR THE CHILD PAGE OF PARENT PAGE ID 689
    }elseif(is_child_of(689)){ 
        // This is a child page of Parent page having id 689  
        get_template_part('content', 'park');
    }else{
        //This is default for anyother page
        get_template_part('content', 'default'); 
    } 
?>
```

The code above, when trying to get the child page of the parent page(689), still renders or rather displays the `get_template_part('content', 'child');` and not `get_template_part('content', 'park');`which i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... Your code is hitting `elseif(is_page() && $post->post_parent )` and stopping there.

```
<?php 
    if(has_children()){ 
        // This is a parent page 
        get_template_part('content', 'parent'); 
    }elseif(is_page() && $post->post_parent ){ 
        // This is a child page of certain parent page
        if(is_child_of(689)){
            // This is a child page of Parent page having id 689  
            get_template_part('content', 'park');
        }else{
            get_template_part('content', 'child');
        }
    }else{
        //This is default for anyother page
        get_template_part('content', 'default'); 
    } 
?>
```